# Connection refused after apache update

Tags: apache-2.2, connection

After I [updated my apache](http://pastebin.com/gRn1T9sf), none of my virtual hosts are accessible anymore, the server responds "Connection refused". No errors are in the logs and I have no idea what is causing this. My virtual host is something like this:

```
 <VirtualHost 173.XXX.XXX.XXX:80>
      ....
      ServerName hostname.com
      ....
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost 173.XXX.XXX.XXX:443>
      ....
      ServerName hostname.com
      ....
 </VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas of how to debug?

Comment: Did you _start_ Apache?

Comment: Of course! The apache is running. I also rebooted the system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Connection refused" would mean that apache is not listening on port 80; run this command to make sure" `lsof -i:80`, if you found no output then start apache and try again

Update: after seeing some output of different commands; it turned out that `libapache2-mod-php5` is not installed according to `dpkg -l | grep apache2` it was flagged as 'rc' (removed, but configuration files remaining).
Since the debug information was showing loading mod_php5 then the absence of this package is what causing apache not to start

Comment: No output is given. Weird... I did `service apache2 start` and returned "Starting web server apache2 [OK]", after I tried `pgrep apache` and no output was shown. Is apache not being initialized, even saying [OK]?!

Comment: try running 'apache2ctl -t' to test your configuration

Comment: Syntax OK. Everything was fine before the update.

Comment: what about running: `apache2ctl -k start` ?

Comment: Tried and no output =/

Comment: let us try: `apache2ctl -k start -e debug`

Comment: Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/xeKiABy5. Something I noticed: /etc/hosts was completely different from what I had setup before the update, maybe some other configuration files were replaced?

Comment: Hmmmm, if you're in doubt and if you got a backup of the old configs, you can run `apache2ctl -f /path/to/old_config`and also review the content on /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Comment: I don't have a backup, I though would be a simple routine update =/
Everything OK under /etc/apache2/sides-enabled. Any way of debbuging more? Additional info: "netstat -nap | grep apache" returns nothing.

Comment: I see you've got some errors in the upgrade with apache2/php packages.. run `dpkg -l | grep apache2`and let us know

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/QJfk9G0k

Comment: Got that, libapache2-mod-php5 is removed. Please run `apt-get installlibapache2-mod-php5` and update the question with the relevant output

Answer (score 7):

Do you have your "Listen" directives in your vhost files or in 
 /etc/apache2/ports.conf?

You should have a line similar to :

```
Listen 80
```

Answer (score 2):

I get this problem every time I get a major upgrade/update on Ubuntu. 
Solved it just by running the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

### apt-get upgrade problems

Another problem I found was that my lightdm stopped working. No GUI prompt after  "apt-get upgrade". I found that lightdm was removed. I installed manually and all started working.

Comment: lightdm has reaaally nothing to do with apache!