# Unable to access apache from port 80, likely due to firewall configuration

Tags: ssl, iptables, apache2, ufw

**Background:** My company hosts two server instances for our internal web-based systems dashboard: a development server and a production server. For added security on the production server, we usually disable port 80 and use a different port to access the webserver. However, our SSL certificates are set to expire soon, so I attempted to re-enable port 80 (to perform the http-01 challenge verification). I was able to enable and renew the certificate on our development machine but cannot do the same on the production machine.

**Problem:** I cannot connect to the Apache webserver that is hosted on an Ubuntu 20.04.1 machine. I've explored numerous resources and similar questions to no avail. I've verified that the Apache `ports.conf` and the `000-default.conf` is listening on port 80. I've also temporarily set the `ufw` / `iptables` configurations to allow all incoming requests in an attempt to rule out the firewall. Currently, if I run `curl http://production.example.com`, it returns a "Connection refused." Based on that, it seems like I'm connecting to the machine, but something is blocking it. **Besides UFW or iptables, is there any service that might be blocking connections to port 80?** Let me know if any more information would be required! Thanks in advance!

**Configurations / Tests**
curl Command:

```
$ curl -v http://production.example.com
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xx.xx:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to xxx.xxx.xx.xx port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to production.example.com port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to production.example.com port 80: Connection refused
```

UFW Settings:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: allow (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Apache `ports.conf` and `000-default.conf`

```
Listen 80
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName production.example.com
        
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Commands to verify Port 80 is open:

```
$ sudo lsof -i:80
COMMAND PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 706     root    4u  IPv6  20604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 752 www-data    4u  IPv6  20604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 759 www-data    4u  IPv6  20604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 764 www-data    4u  IPv6  20604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 767 www-data    4u  IPv6  20604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 774 www-data    4u  IPv6  20604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

$ netstat -a | grep http | grep LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

**Similar Questions**

- [Connection refused after apache update](https://serverfault.com/questions/488257/connection-refused-after-apache-update)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1187495/apache-2-4-reachable-but-refusing-the-connection

**--Update--**
As per the comments, I ran the command described in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message), but I'm not sure how to interpret the results:

```
sudo tcpdump -n host 138.197.97.12 and port 80
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
17:31:56.921857 IP 47.33.203.205.59520 > 138.197.97.12.80: Flags [S], seq 1979773428, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 362696691 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
17:31:57.936229 IP 47.33.203.205.59520 > 138.197.97.12.80: Flags [S], seq 1979773428, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 362697692 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
17:32:08.748828 IP 35.190.73.167.80 > 138.197.97.12.4957: Flags [S.], seq 3923531534, ack 2621902277, win 65535, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 2683344831 ecr 873100626,nop,wscale 8], length 0
17:32:16.798047 IP 47.33.203.205.59520 > 138.197.97.12.80: Flags [S], seq 1979773428, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 362715694 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

Comment: There might be an additional network firewall (in addition to the host based ufw/iptables firewall) that blocks the connection

Comment: How would I go about checking this? I am able to ```curl``` the hostname / web URL from that machine and get a valid response (if that helps?)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/725262/546643 Describes that